# How to add Options validation on startup of command-line .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to figure out a way to have my command-line application validate its configuration options on startup.

I have a C#11/.NET 7 solution with two projects - one web application and one command-line scheduled task runner.  In both, we want our Options classes to be injectable.

The web application validation went smoothly:

```csharp
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddOptions<MailConfig>()
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart()
    .BindConfiguration("Mail");
builder.Services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AuthConfig>>().Value);
```

However, I'm having difficulty replicating that on the command line.

Basically how it works now is:

```csharp
var collection = new ServiceCollection();
collection.AddOptions<MailConfig>()
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .BindConfiguration("Mail");
collection.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MailConfig>>().Value);
```

`.ValidateDataAnnotations()` exists because I installed the Nuget package "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations".  Before that package was installed, the only option was to call `.Validate()` to manually set-up validation.  For some reason, `.ValidateOnStart()` doesn't exist in IOptionsBuilder on the command line app.

I found this article: https://keestalkstech.com/2019/09/validate-strongly-typed-options-when-using-config-sections/, which mentions using `PostConfigure()`.  I can do that, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I'm just missing `.ValidateOnStart()` somehow.

*Please note that I didn't write this app and I'm fairly new to C#/.NET, so please forgive any ignorance or missing salient information.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the [`ValidateOnStart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsbuilderextensions.validateonstart) available in the console application,
make sure you have the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) NuGet package included, version 6 or higher.

An ASP.NET Core web application has an implicit reference to that package.

From the documentation

> Namespace:
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
> Assembly: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll
> Package: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting v7.0.0

Comment: Thank you!  I was sure I was missing something straightforward.

Comment: Indeed - need to explicitly add this package or it won't fire